# Trouble consuming XLedger's SOAP/WSDL interface

Tags: java, python, soap, wsdl

I'm having trouble figuring out how to consume this [WSDL interface](https://ws.xledger.net/WS/Common/Lib/Export.asmx?WSDL). I have zero experience with WSDL (and SOAP in general).

It all goes completely over my head. My case is the following. I have a web app that uses a REST interface to communicate with a backend. The backend needs to communicate with the mentioned WSDL interface to provide the web app with the information it requests.

So

```
[Client] <-- REST --> [Server] <-- SOAP --> [XLedger]
```

I think I need a tutorial that is aimed at complete SOAP newbies. There are too many gaps right now, I can't extrapolate from the articles to build what I need. Or maybe a helpful SO member can show me some sample code to get me started?

To be more specific I'm interested in [GetTimesheetEntriesData](https://ws.xledger.net/WS/Common/Lib/Export.asmx?op=GetTimesheetEntriesData) and the attributes it provides. I just want to be able to call the getters and send the data to the web app (running on a smart phone).

I'm not even sure I'm asking the right question here, **but how do I get user timesheet data using the WSDL interface?**

[EDIT]

Here's the interface for authentication: https://ws.xledger.net/WS/Common/Lib/Authentication.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I had to make use of [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) first.

```
import httplib
import urllib2 as u2
from suds.transport.http import HttpTransport


class HTTPSClientAuthHandler(u2.HTTPSHandler):
    def __init__(self, key, cert):
        u2.HTTPSHandler.__init__(self)
        self.key = key
        self.cert = cert

    def https_open(self, req):
        # Rather than pass in a reference to a connection class, we pass in
        # a reference to a function which, for all intents and purposes,
        # will behave as a constructor
        return self.do_open(self.getConnection, req)

    def getConnection(self, host, timeout=300):
        return httplib.HTTPSConnection(host, key_file=self.key, cert_file=self.cert)


class HTTPSClientCertTransport(HttpTransport):
    def __init__(self, key, cert, *args, **kwargs):
        HttpTransport.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.key = key
        self.cert = cert

    def u2open(self, u2request):
        """
        Open a connection.

        @param u2request: A urllib2 request.
        @type u2request: urllib2.Request.
        @return: The opened file-like urllib2 object.
        @rtype: fp
        """
        url = u2.build_opener(HTTPSClientAuthHandler(self.key, self.cert))
        if self.u2ver() < 2.6:
            return url.open(u2request)
        else:
            return url.open(u2request, timeout=self.options.timeout)
.
.
.
def consume_soap():
    from suds.client import Client
    from datetime import date
    from calendar import monthrange

    transport = HTTPSClientCertTransport('auth/key_no_passphrase.pem', 'auth/cert.pem')
    client = Client(XLedgerInterface.WSDL_EXPORT_PATH, transport=transport)
    year = date.today().year
    month = date.today().month
    first_date = str(date(year, month, 1))
    last_date = str(date(year, month, monthrange(year, month)[1]))
    xml = client.service.GetTimesheetEntriesData(sUserName=XLedgerInterface.USER_ID,
                                                 sKey=XLedgerInterface.KEY,
                                                 sApplication=XLedgerInterface.APPLICATION_NAME,
                                                 iEntityCode=XLedgerInterface.ENTITY_CODE,
                                                 dDateFrom=first_date,
                                                 dDateTo=last_date,
                                                 sFreeText='',
                                                 sFilter='',
                                                 eOption="Open")
    return self._get_as_json(xml)
```